# I want to add months into a date and get in mm/dd/yy format

Tags: javascript

I want to add number of months into a particular date and get the result in the mm/dd/yy format using javascript

Eg ; Here is my date  04/01/2016

My Frequencies are Annually , Every Six Months , Every 3 months,  Every 2 months , Monthly , Twice  a month , Every two weeks , Weekly , Every four weeks ,Onetime .

If i select the monthly option , the result date should be 05/01/2016

Can anyone help me on this ?

Comment: `new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()+NUMBER_OF_DAYS)`

Comment: But how can we caluclate the Number of days ?

Comment: To add one month: `new Date().setMonth(new Date().getMonth()+1);`

Comment: you need to add a switch to handle the conditions

Comment: Where can i pass my date which i want to add months , the date is not the todays date , this may vary. , can you please specific ?

Comment: Try moment api..it's awesome..Link : http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you'll need to get your date into a `Date` object.

```
var myDate = new Date("2016-04-01 00:00:00");
```

`Date` needs the input to be formatted in the [ISO format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

You can then use the following to add different numbers of months:

```
var myDate_6Months = new Date(myDate.setMonth(myDate.getMonth() + 6));
```

The line above creates a new `Date` object by grabbing your original date's month, and adding a desired amount of months to it.

If you were to output `myDate_6Months` you would get:

```
Sat Oct 01 2016 00:00:00
```

To add 11 months:

```
var myDate_11Months = new Date(myDate.setMonth(myDate.getMonth() + 11))
```

which would result in:

```
Wed Mar 01 2017 00:00:00
```

In order to get the date back in the `mm/dd/yy` one easy method is to use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

```
moment(myDate_6Months).format('MM/DD/YY')
```

Comment: I already tried this method , but i need to get the date in MM/DD/YY format  (03/01/2017)and not like 'Wed Mar 01 2017 00:00:00' and doesn't want display the time . Only want to get the date (eg :  03/01/2017)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you will add days on some event I explained click event here.

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li><button data-add="1 year">Add Year</button></li>
    <li><button data-add="6 month">Add 6 month</button></li>
    <li><button data-add="3 month">Add 3 month</button></li>
    <li><button data-add="2 month">Add 2 month</button></li>
    <li><button data-add="1 month">Add 1 month</button></li>
    <li><button data-add="2 weeks">Add 2 weeks</button></li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
    console.log("button click");
    var myDate = new Date();
    console.log(myDate);
    var timeSpan = $(this).attr("data-add");
    switch(timeSpan) {
      case "1 year":
        myDate = myDate.setFullYear(myDate.getFullYear() + 1);
        break;
      case "3 month":
        myDate = myDate.setMonth(myDate.getMonth() + 3);
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  console.log(myDate);
  moment(myDate).format('MM/DD/YYYY');//include moment js to format date
});
```

With above code you can add the specifc time to date. for formatting date you can use moment.js

jsbin is [here](http://jsbin.com/tawuxuligi/edit?html,js,output)